# How can I equip items faster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to equip armor without going into the inventory screen? In PvP, it would be more ideal to be able to equip on the move. Is there any way to do this, or otherwise equip up faster?

Comment: you can shift click armor into place so pressing E then shift clicking and then E again can be pretty fast, or try to find a quiet spot first

Comment: Some people use client-side mods to auto-replace damaged armor and weapons, but most servers count this as cheating and getting caught (or reported, then caught) will earn a permanent ban.

Comment: You might consider choosing the answer that best addresses your question.

Answer (score 12):

If you have armor on your hotbar, you can hold it in your hand and right click. Other than that, your only option is to open your inventory and equip up as quickly as possible using Shift+Click.

Answer (score 4):

Options for equipping armor are:

- Shift click (mentioned in comments on your question)
- Hot-bar click (mentioned in the other answer)
- Dispenser while you stand in front of it (this was added for adventure mode, but it should work in survival and creative as well)

Equipping armor at some random location (on the move would be random) you are probably not interested in placing dispensers and pressure plates (or other redstone) and loading the armor into it. The first two options are your non-modded options.

If you are looking for mods to do it, then search for them specifically. I'm sure there are hundreds of options out there (with varying degrees of functionality).

Answer (score 0):

In your inventory, you can immediately equip armor by right-clicking it.  It will snap to the appropriate body slot.

Answer (score 0):

If your shift click doesn't work then you can go into e and put you mouse on an item don't press down and then click the number you want the item to go to into your hand inventory. you click 3 or 1 or any other number